# How to rename storyboard and have links from other storyboards preserved

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two storyboards in Xcode project.

First named `Main` and second `Settings`. `Main` storyboard has storyboard reference to `Settings`.

I want to rename `Settings` storyboard to `AppSettings`. But when I rename it through Xcode Project Navigator, `Main` storyboard reference to `Settings` is not automatically updated and project fails to compile.

[image]

Of course, I can manually update broken reference, but I wonder is there another way of renaming storyboard in Xcode that would automatically update existing storyboard references?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Xcode's Find navigator can perform a find & replace operation that includes references inside storyboards. Search for "Settings" and replace it with "AppSettings". Then click "Preview" so you can choose only the relevant instances of "Settings" to replace (I'm assuming that word will appear in unrelated places, since it's rather common.) Afterwards, you will still have to rename the file itself as usual.

[image: Find navigator]